# Is there a good solution for using AWS ALB to connect a k8s cluster which installed by kops?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, dns, kubernetes, load-balancing

For special reazon, our project should use AWS ALB(not ELB) or NLB to catch an application in k8s cluster.
We are using kops to manage the k8s cluster. It seems its load balancer stategy is using ELB for AWS cloud.

I have researched some approach to realize it:

- ELB
  https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/tree/master/addons/ingress-nginx
- ALB
  https://github.com/coreos/alb-ingress-controller
- External-DNS
  https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns

About the second ALB, it shows:

> NOTE: This controller is in alpha state as we attempt to move to our first 1.0 release. The current image version is 1.0-alpha.3. Please file any issues you find and note the version used.

So it seems that it isn't a good choice for production environment.

Then, what's the good way?

Comment: As merely a "for your consideration," while they say it is alpha, it seems reasonable to audit any outstanding issues on CoreOS project, try it in your pre-prod environment, and so long as the bugs don't bother you, then it will help you meet the ALB need and help them by providing valuable feedback from running the project under duress. In short, so long as the actual bugs don't overlap with your specific uses, then it is alpha in name only

Comment: As a follow-up, for that first link you mentioned, we've been using the [same nginx-ingress container](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx#readme) as from their descriptors, with ours at approximately 0.9.0-beta.4 or so, and it seems to work well once the memory is tuned for the number of Ingress resources. They also recently [released 0.9.0](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/releases/tag/nginx-0.9.0), so while not an ALB, it shouldn't be dismissed outright, either.

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel Thank you for your reply. I have researched many resources that `alb-ingress-controller` seems the best choice. Even Amazon wrote a blog about using it for its ALB: https://aws.amazon.com/cn/blogs/apn/coreos-and-ticketmaster-collaborate-to-bring-aws-application-load-balancer-support-to-kubernetes/